# Spherical coordinates, chart, manifold, differential geometry

Tags: differential-geometry

I have some doubts about the definition of the chart of manifold applied to the sphere $ S^2 $ embedded in $ R^3 $.
In every document I read, the example chart for the sphere is obtained using the stereography projection. No one takes as an example the inverse of the parametrization (for example the sphere of radius = 1)

$$\begin{eqnarray} 
x = \sin( \theta)\cos( \gamma )\\
y = \sin( \theta)\sin( \gamma )\\
z = \cos (\theta)\\
\end{eqnarray}$$

Why nobody cites this example?
Isn't it a chart?

The only reason I may guess is the fact that in order to know the values of $\gamma$,$\theta$ corresponding to a point on a sphere the center of the sphere is needed and this is an element outside the surface of the sphere.
Am I correct?

thank you

Answer (score 1):

In do Carmo's book, Differential Geometry of Curves and Surfaces, page 56, he uses this parametrization (inverse function of a chart).

In fact, this is a parametrization, and you can use this function on $\theta\in (0,2\pi)$ and $\gamma\in (0,\pi)$ in order to make this defined on an open set, a requirement parametrizations and charts.